# Returning a table from PL/SQL function - incorrect datatype

Tags: plsql

I have got a problem with my function that should return a table. But, when I want to run this function, the error "Incorrect datatype" is returned. Anyway package is compilling right.

I have no idea where is the problem.

Here is my code:

```
    create or replace package PKG_BORROW as
    type advertisement_header is record(
    id_advertisment number,
    title   varchar2(100),
    date_added timestamp,
    username varchar2(100),
    regionName varchar2(100),
    id_category number
    );
    type adv_head_tab is table of advertisement_header;



    enter code here

   function get_adv_header_filter
  (title varchar2,username varchar2,regionName varchar2,categoryName varchar2)
  return adv_head_tab;

  end ;

  /
  create or replace package body PKG_BORROW 
  as

  function get_adv_header_filter
  (title varchar2,username varchar2,regionName varchar2,categoryName varchar2)
  return adv_head_tab as
  l_tab adv_head_tab := adv_head_tab();
  query varchar2(500);
   TYPE CurTyp  IS REF CURSOR;
  v_adv_cursor    CurTyp;

  begin
    query:='select a.id_advertisement,a.title,a.date_added,a.id_user,r.name,i.id_item_category from advertisement a,region r,item_category i
    where a.id_region=r.id_region and a.id_item_category=i.id_item_category ';

    open v_adv_cursor for query;
    loop
        fetch v_adv_cursor into l_tab(l_tab.last);
        exit when v_adv_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    end loop;
   close v_adv_cursor;
   dbms_output.put_line(l_tab(1).title);
    return l_tab;
  end;

end ;

  /
  select * from TABLE(PKG_BORROW.get_adv_header_filter('a','a','a','a'));

  /
  declare
     TYPE CurTyp  IS REF CURSOR;
  v_adv_cursor    CurTyp;
  begin 
  open v_adv_cursor for PKG_BORROW.get_adv_header_filter('a','a','a','a');

  end;
```

UPDATE: Well, I made my code simpler, but still I have 00902 error "invalid datatype". New code I'm showing below:

```
     create or replace package PKG_BORROW as
    type adv_head_tab is table of ADVERTISEMENT%ROWTYPE;
   function get_adv_header_filter
  return adv_head_tab;

  end ;

  /
  create or replace package body PKG_BORROW 
  as

  function get_adv_header_filter
  return adv_head_tab as
  l_tab adv_head_tab := adv_head_tab();
  query varchar2(500);
   TYPE CurTyp  IS REF CURSOR;
  v_adv_cursor    CurTyp;

 begin
    query:='select * from ADVERTISEMENT';

    open v_adv_cursor for query;

    fetch v_adv_cursor bulk collect into l_tab;

   close v_adv_cursor;


   for rec in 1..l_tab.count
   loop        
     dbms_output.put_line(l_tab(rec).title);
   end loop;

    return l_tab;
  end;
end ;

  /
  select  * from TABLE(PKG_BORROW.get_adv_header_filter);
```

The error about invalid datatypes still exists.

Comment: A PL/SQL table is not a cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function has problem. You are trying insert cursor values to a collection in a loop. You need to do bulk collect. See below:

```
 function get_adv_header_filter
  (title varchar2,username varchar2,regionName varchar2,categoryName varchar2)
  return adv_head_tab as
  l_tab adv_head_tab := adv_head_tab();
  query varchar2(500);
   TYPE CurTyp  IS REF CURSOR;
  v_adv_cursor    CurTyp;

  begin
    query:='select a.id_advertisement,a.title,a.date_added,a.id_user,r.name,i.id_item_category from advertisement a,region r,item_category i
    where a.id_region=r.id_region and a.id_item_category=i.id_item_category ';

    open v_adv_cursor for query;

    fetch v_adv_cursor bulk collect into l_tab;

   close v_adv_cursor;


   for rec in 1..l_tab.count
   loop        
     dbms_output.put_line(l_tab(rec).title);
   end loop;

    return l_tab;
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - your fixed code works. I have got other question - did you see the select in the bottom part of my code? The execution of this select does not run -> invalid datatypes error, so I can't to run it. That arguments in function call are not important - just I want to run this type of select. When I my put my structures in the schema level, I got these kind of error: "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if your `record` column datatype is matching with the columns being selected in select statement.